# Mule upgrade 3.6 compiler error

Tags: java, rest, jersey, mule

I was working on mule 3.5.1, when I upgrade to mule 3.6 version, getting compile time error for following class:

```
import org.mule.module.jersey.MuleResponseWriter;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse;


public class GLExportTransformer extends AbstractMessageTransformer {

    public List<GLExport> methodType(@Payload MuleResponseWriter content){
        List<GLExport> glExportList = (List<GLExport>) content;
        System.out.println("Java payload is -->"+glExportList.getClass());
        return glExportList ;
    } 

    @Override
    public Object transformMessage(MuleMessage message, String outputEncoding)throws TransformerException {
        ContainerResponse cr = (ContainerResponse) message.getInvocationProperty("jersey_response");
        List<GLExport> res = (List<GLExport>)cr.getResponse().getEntity();
        System.out.println("Response from QB is -->"+res);
        return res;   
    }

}

<custom-transformer name="StringToNameString" class="com.trinet.qb.utils.GLExportTransformer" doc:name="GL Export Transformer"/>
```

Compile time error:

```
The type org.mule.module.jersey.MuleResponseWriter is not visible

The import com.sun.jersey cannot be resolved
```

How do I resolve this?

In my Anypoint Studio shows Mule3.6 uses all jersey related jar uses 2.11 version of jar files. Using Java 1.7 version.

**EDIT:**

Here is my rest component(GLExportService):

```
@POST
@Path("/post")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<GLExport> postOperation(@Payload String content) throws ParseException {
    System.out.println("Content from Reporting page-->\n\n"+content+"\n\n");
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    Object jsonObjectInstance =null;
    try {
        jsonObjectInstance = jsonParser.parse(new StringReader(content));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    // parse json and assign to dto as glExportList
    return glExportList;
```

Here is my mule flows:

```
 <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="${hostname}" port="${glport}" path="QBJournalExport/QBGLRest" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <jersey:resources doc:name="REST"> 
            <component class="com.qb.rest.GLExportService"/>
        </jersey:resources> 
<set-session-variable variableName="accessToken" value="#[payload.get(0).get('ACCESS_TOKEN')]" doc:name="Access token"/>
<set-session-variable variableName="accessTokenSecret" value="#[payload.get(0).get('ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET')]" doc:name="Access Secret"/>
<set-session-variable variableName="realmId" value="#[payload.get(0).get('ACCT_SYSTEM_COMPANY_ID')]" doc:name="Company ID"/>
<set-session-variable variableName="quickbooksClient" value="#[com.qb.utils.QuickbooksUtils.getQuickbooksClient(sessionVars['accessToken'],sessionVars['accessTokenSecret'],'${consumerKey}','${consumerSecret}','${appToken}',sessionVars['realmId'])]" doc:name="QB Client"/>
<custom-transformer name="StringToNameString" class="com.qb.utils.GLExportTransformer" doc:name="GL Export Transformer"/>
<set-payload value="#[com.qb.utils.CreateJournalEntry.createJournalEntry(payload,sessionVars['accessToken'],sessionVars['accessTokenSecret'],'${consumerKey}','${consumerSecret}','${appToken}', sessionVars['realmId'])]" doc:name="Create Journal Entry"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerResponse;

public class GLExportTransformer extends AbstractMessageTransformer {

    @Override
    public Object transformMessage(MuleMessage message, String outputEncoding)throws TransformerException {
        ContainerResponse cr = (ContainerResponse) message.getInvocationProperty("jersey_response");
        List<GLExport> res = (List<GLExport>)cr.getEntity();
        return res;   
    }

}
```

method  called methodType was a dummy code.

Answer (score 1):

Try making the parameter type `java.util.Object`, and removing the import.  You are immediately casting it to `List<GLExport>` anyway, so you don't appear to need that type.

Comment: transformMessage is is a overridden method, changing parameter will cause compiler error.

Comment: The main thing you need to accomplish is to produce a List<GLExport> given the JSON you receive from the client.  If you are expecting the client to POST a JSON representation of a List<GLExport>, you can use <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.List" /> before the <jersey:resources /> or maybe just change the parameter type in the postOperation method and see if jersey will transform it for you.

Comment: you said change the parameter type in the postOperation method and see if jersey will transform it for you, what to change? my input data i.e String content is json data in string format

Comment: Try changing it to List<GLExport>.  I think Jersey has built in Jackson marshalling... if not, you can always use the json transformer before the resources element.

Answer (score 1):

We indeed made MuleResponseWriter package only, but that's not the root of your problem. In Mule 3.6 we upgraded from Jersey 1.6 to 2.11. Jersey 2 is quite different, it even includes a package rename from com.sun.jersey to org.glassfish.jersey. You can find more information about the upgrade in this post, including a link to Jersey's migration guide: http://blogs.mulesoft.org/mule-3-6-api/

What I don't understand anyway, is why you need to access the ContainerResponse in your transformer instead of having your jersey resource set the message payload to the List directly.

Regards

Comment: I am having the same problem.  Older documentation about the Jersey Module recommended using ContainerResponse in the manner above "to transform or send the request from your jersey component to next resource/flow".  See the very bottom of this page linked here:  http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/34X/Jersey+Module+Reference

Comment: updated with mule flows and components. Input is json data from one system which invokes rest component and sends/receives data from rest and upload to cloud based application-QuickBooks

Answer (score 0):

It seems they made the class org.mule.module.jersey.MuleResponseWriter package only.

This could be because the class was never part of the public Mule API or just minor typo.

Anyways, as it is right now there is no much you can do.
The only hack is to place the transformer and any class that references org.mule.module.jersey.MuleResponseWriter inside a package named:
org.mule.module.jersey

BUT THIS IS A HACK, and I wouldn't advise it. 
I'll try to find out if was made on purpose and let you know ;)